Help on how to upload an image using JSON API with Python
I wrote this Python code. It seems to complain about this error that I don't seem to be able solve. I don't know what this id needs to be (for a new image). If I don't pass the ID, it complains No ID.
{"jsonapi":{"version":"1.0","meta":{"links":{"self":{"href":"http:\/\/jsonapi.org\/format\/1.0\/"}}}},"errors":[{"title":"Bad Request","status":"400","detail":"**No ID specified for related resource**","links":{"via":{"href":"http:\/\/mydrupalcms.com\/jsonapi\/media\/single_image"},"info":{"href":"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/Protocols\/rfc2616\/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1"}}}]}

This is the code I am using.
import requests
import base64

# Replace with your Drupal base URL and credentials
base_url = 'https://mydrupalurl.com'
username = 'myusername'               # Drupal username
password = 'mypassword'       # Drupal password

# Image file path on your local system
image_path = 'article_image.png'

# Prepare the image file for upload
with open(image_path, 'rb') as image_file:
    image_data = image_file.read()
    image_base64 = base64.b64encode(image_data).decode('utf-8')
# Prepare the JSON payload
data = {
    'data': {
        'type': 'media--single_image',
        'attributes': {
            'name': 'article_image.png'
        },
        'relationships': {
            'field_media_image': {
                'data': {
                    'type': 'file--file',
                     'id': None,
                    'attributes': {
                        'filename': image_path,
                        'data': image_base64,
                        'uri': {
                            'value': f'base64://{image_base64}'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
# Prepare the headers with authentication
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.api+json',
}
# Authenticate using basic auth
auth = (username, password)

# Make the POST request to create the single image entity
response = requests.post(f'{base_url}/jsonapi/media/single_image', json=data, headers=headers, auth=auth)

# Check the response status
if response.status_code == 201:
    # Single image entity created successfully
    response_data = response.json()
    media_id = response_data['data']['id']
    print(f"Single image entity with ID {media_id} created successfully.")
else:
    # Handle errors
    print(f"Failed to create single image entity. Status code: {response.status_code}")
    print(response.text)


I think you have to upload the image first, get its ID, then attach it to a media.

See the change record about this.
Drupal is a little confusing here because I often think of "media" as "files", but to Drupal, "media" is the "entity" and the file is a field on that entity.
So, to add a file with JSON:API, if the entity already exists, you can post the file directly to the entity as binary data.
But, if you are trying to create a new entity, you need to add the file to Drupal first and then create the entity with a relationship attaching the file.  This is described in the linked change record.
